# Using curl to simulate Internet Explorer's auto logon

Tags: networking, internet-explorer, http, curl, windows-authentication

I have a webpage on my intranet in which Internet Explorer can automatically login using whatever user is logged in the network.

How can I use curl (or: what are the HTTP headers I need) in order to make the exact same request Internet Explorer does and get the same page Internet Explorer gets.

I tried using Internet Explorer's Developer Tools, but there is no request in there which sends REMOTE_USER, nor any other meaningful header, so I guess whatever it is doing, is behind curtains.

Comment: You didn't mentioned the authentication method however you may consider this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044315/how-to-set-the-authorization-header-using-curl

Comment: That was the exact question: which kind of authentication do IE uses when auto logon is enabled for intranet sites?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a full answer without knowing more, but at a minimum, set the `User-Agent` header. For instance, to mimic IE9:

```
curl -A 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0)' <other options> <url>
```

It might respond with a session variable and cookies, which you then need to propagate. The session variables have to be sort of programmatically copied and sent along with `-H` option of your next curl invocation. The cookies can be managed by curl with `-b` and `-c`. Again, without specifics, no can-do on examples.